# Generalization of Eigenspaces to Vector Bundles

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Suppose we have a vector bundle $E$ over a smooth manifold $M$, and let $F$ be a vector bundle endomorphism $E$.

Is there anyway to now generalize the theory of eigenspaces in linear algebra to vector bundles? In particular, I am wondering when it is possible to construct sub bundles which correspond to some family of “eigenvalues” of $F$, and whose Whitney sum is isomorphic to $E$.

In the case where $F$ restricts to a linear isomorphism, which in each fibre has eigenvalues $\pm 1$, it’s not very difficult to construct an isomorphism:

$E\leftrightarrow E^+\oplus E^-$

But trying to generalize this to multiple constant eigenvalues seems difficult, and generalizing this further to non constant eigenvalues seems very difficult.

For context, I am trying to show that every manifold that admits a pseudo-riemannian metric of signature $(t,s)$ splits as a Whitney sum of a positive definite, and negative definite subbundle, and I have an idea that hinges on this generalization. I have unfortunately found no source which either $a)$ proves this statement (though I suspect it to be true) , or $b)$ goes into such a generalization.

If anyone has any reference suggestions, or can provide some help on the path to this generalization it would be of much help.

Comment: The bundle disappeared in your ultimate question. What does an indefinite metric have to do with a bundle endomorphism?

Comment: @TedShifrin impose a riemannian metric on the bundle, using the musical isomorphism we can then turn the indefinite metric into a fibrewise self adjoint linear map. I suspect I can organize these fibres in a nice way base of the eigenvalues of this linear map into vector sub bundles, but I don’t know how.

Comment: @TedShifrin though my motivation for such a generalization comes from this problem in pseudo riemannian geometry, I am also just interested in this generalization in its own right. It seems pretty interesting as a general theory in and of itself

Comment: It’s still muddled to me. What does a metric on the base manifold have to do with an arbitrary vector bundle? Can you be completely explicit?

Comment: @TedShifrin impose a riemannian $\text{bundle}$ metric on $E$. This provides an isomorphism between $E$ and $E^*$. In particular it provides an isomorphism between $E^*\otimes E^*$ and  $\text{Hom}(E,E)$. We can use this isomorphism to turn the indefinite metric on $E$ into non trivial endomorphism on $E$. Fibrewise, this endomorphism is self adjoint with respect to the bundle metric on that fibre, and has a number of positive eigenvalues and negative eigenvalues equal to its signature. I want to then be able to say something about smooth subbundles, but am unsure how.

Comment: I haven't given much thought to this, but you need to know at least that the dimension of these positive and negative spaces is constant. Once you have that, you can try to define the splitting you are interested in locally, over a local trivialization of the bundle. Then you check if *the transition functions of your bundle preserve the positive and negative spaces*. Once this is done (if it can be done), you should have the decomposition you are after.

Comment: The issue, boiled down to linear algebra, is that the eigenvectors/eigenspaces of a linear map $A:V\to V$ do not depend "continuously" on $A$ in any suitable sense without some additional restrictions. You can (and should) try to sidestep the issue of eigendecompositions entirely when constructing this splitting.

Comment: @Kajelad could you possibly elaborate on both your points? Specifically, what’s another way of constructing such a splitting? And why does the eigenspaces not depending continuously on $A$ matter? Shouldn’t we want them to depend continuously on the base space?

Comment: The collection of all vector fields on your bundle is itself a vector space, and $F$ is a linear operator on that space. Thus you can discuss the eigenvalues and eigenvectors it has. But the vector space is now infinite dimensional, and this affects the eigen theory. It is now called "spectral analysis", and is a subject in Functional Analysis. I suggest you look into that theory and see what it can tell you about your particular application.

Comment: @Chris To your second point: when working in a local trivialization, continuous dependence of the eigenspaces on the base space is equivalent to continuous dependence of the eigenspaces on the linear operator, since in that trivialization $F$ is effectively a family of parameterized linear operators.

Comment: @Chris As for alternate routes, the essential piece of topology is that the space of positive-definite $p$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ is contractible (it is isomorphic to the space of maps $A:\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^q$ with $\|A\|_{op}<1$). Thus, the bundle of such subspaces on a pseudo-inner product bundle admits a global section.

Comment: @Kajelad do you think you could provide a more detailed response  in the form of an answer? If you don't have the time I understand, but I am not entirely sure how to see your alternate route.

Comment: In light of Johnny's comment, does the following not give a counterexample? Let $E=[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$ and $T$ to linearly interpolate between the 0 map and the identity map. Then the dimension of the eigenspace isn't constant.

Comment: @Mr.Brown I am not sure what this gives a counter example to?

Comment: This gives an example of a bundle with an endomoprhism which doesn't admit an bundle eigenspace decomposition, even though each fiber does, since the dimension of the positive spaces goes from $1$ to $0$. So whatever your theory of eigenspaces of bundles ends up being, assuming one exists, you will need to accommodate this simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the argument you're trying to make is that, without additional restrictions, the eigenspaces of a vector bundle endomorphism can merge, split, and change dimension in complicated ways not easily described using the language of vector bundles. Luckily, there are other ways to achieve the decomposition you describe. I'll address only the positive definite case; the negative definite argument is essentially identical.

**Some linear algebra:**

Let $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ be $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$ equipped with the standard pseudo-inner product of signature $(p,q)$, and let $N\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ be the negative definite subspace spanned by the last $q$ coordinates.

Let $\operatorname{Gr}(p,\mathbb{R}^{p,q})$, denote the [Grasmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) of rank $p$ (that is, the set of $p$-dimensional subspaces equipped with the natural smooth manifold structure). The set of positive definite subspaces is a subset which I'll call $\Delta\subseteq\operatorname{Gr}(p,\mathbb{R}^{p,q})$. Note that each element of $\Delta$ is complimentary to $N$. Thus, each element of $\Delta$ may be written as $\{(\vec{x},A\vec{x}):\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^p\}$ where $A$ is a $q\times p$ matrix. Further, each $q\times p$ matrix $A$ corresponds to a unique subspace, which is an element of $\Delta$ iff $\|A\|_{op}<1$. This gives us a diffeomorphism from $\Delta$ to $\{A\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times p}:\|A\|_{op}<1\}$, which is a smoothly contractible open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{q\times p}$.

**Vector Bundles**

Given a rank $p+q$ smooth vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$ with a bundle pseudo-metric $g$ of signature $p,q$, there is a corresponding bundle $\pi_{\Delta}:E_\Delta\to M$ where the fiber over $x\in M$ is the set of positive definite subspaces of $\pi^{-1}(x)\subseteq E$. The typical fiber of $\pi_\Delta$ is of course just $\Delta$ from above. Since the typical fiber is contractible, $\pi_{\Delta}$ admits a smooth global section (see [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25866/smooth-sections-of-smooth-fiber-bundles) for more discussion). These sections are exactly the subbundles that you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, a beautiful argument. I don't understand all the details, but this is definitely enough to send me down the right path. Thank you. I am still wondering however if there is some theory of eigenspaces of vector bundle endomorphisms where the restrictions are laid out, and the results are summarized, but perhaps it's just not that useful.

Comment: @Chris An instructive example for the eigenvector bit is the bundle $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where bundle endomorphisms are just smooth one-parameter families on $n\times n$ matrices $A(t)$. There's plenty of discussion here and on MO about this kind of thing, e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116123/how-to-find-define-eigenvectors-as-a-continuous-function-of-matrix). The simplest condition for smoothly varying eigenspaces is that $A(t)$ is everywhere diagonalizable with $n$ *distinct* eigenvalues, but there are others.

Comment: I see, but does that give any type of splitting of the bundle? Like if I have a vector bundle endomorphism which is everywhere diagonalizable, such that the eigenvalues are smooth functions on the base space, do I get a splitting into $n$ line bundles?

Comment: @Chris Not necessarily; issues can arise when the eigenvalues coincide. If you add the requirement that the eigenvalues are everywhere distinct (or, more generally, have constant multiplicities), then you get the desired splitting.

Comment: ok I think I see, do you know if a source which details questions like this?

Comment: @Chris I don't know of a source for this specific topic. That said, in my previous comment, the main piece of vector bundle theory is a standard theorem that the kernel of a *constant rank* homomorphism is a subbundle. See for instance theorem 10.34 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.